# While installing node js, the command apt -get -f install gave error

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

It recommended I run `sudo apt-get -f install` but there is an error.

[image: Error]

Comment: What you are trying to install?

Comment: Please do not post error texts as screenshot but post the message through copy paste and mark it as a code block

Comment: Also keep in mind that for question about Ubuntu there is: https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: use https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation#how-to-install-nodejs-via-binary-archive-on-linux

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install Node.js in ubuntu. you can check [Node installation on ubuntu](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install npm

sudo npm install npm --global
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to install any version between Node.js v6.9.0 - 6.10.0 , use the below commands**

$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash

$ nvm ls

$ nvm install v6.9.5

**To check your npm and node versions**

$ npm -v

$ node -v

Answer (score 0):

Error caused by a package flashplugin-installer as we can clearly see in line:

> dpkg:error processing package flashplugin-installer (--configure)

Run following command to remove that:

```
    apt-get purge remove flashplugin-installer
```

Then try to install again, if got another error then comment

Comment: sudo apt-get purge remove flashplugin-installer                                                                                        
[sudo] password for mohit: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
**E: Unable to locate package remove**